# visual studio - not enough storage available to complete

Tags: sql-server, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am developing a wpf application, I load my image paths from the sql server than i have all the images saved in a folder under solution. My images are about 200MB after a build my visual studio starts giving me an error, "Not enough storage available to complete this process".

btw what is the best way to display images from database, should i just copy it under solution or is there any other way i can link up the images.

any help is appreciated

thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you setup publishing or making deployment package or something of that kind and VS tries to copy all your media files to another location without enough free space.

You can look at [FILESTREAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - also check this and other articles for recomendations on particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Please Close Visual Studio before start this operation

1. Start your Visual Studio Command Prompt as an administrator.
2. Type "BCDEDIT /Set IncreaseUserVa 3072" - It will change the boot configuration so that the user mode memory would be 3GB going forward.
3. Change your directory to where devenv.exe is lying like : C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9\Common7\IDE\
4. Type editbin /LARGEADDRESSAWARE devenv.exe
5. Restart your computer.

Command line like this:

> BCDEDIT /Set IncreaseUserVa 3072 (Hit Enter)
>   editbin /LARGEADDRESSAWARE devenv.exe  (Hit Enter)

Now Reboot your Machine.